# Show that $E\exp(-tX_i) \leq \frac{1}{t}$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, moment-generating-functions

This is exercise 2.2.10 present in the book High-Dimensional Probability, by Vershynin.
Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be non-negative independent r.v with the densities bounded by $1.$ Show that the MGF of $X_i$ satisfies
$$
E \exp(-tX_i)\leq \frac{1}{t}
$$
After that, deduce that for any $\varepsilon >0$, one has
$$
P\left(
\sum^n_{i=1}X_i \leq \varepsilon n
\right)\leq 
(e\varepsilon)^n
$$

Some help would be much appreciated. I was not able to prove event the first inequality. This question is present in the section dealing with Hoeffding's inequality, so it probably is used somehow.

Comment: write the expected value as an integral and bound the density with 1. You will get a classical integral of an exponential

Comment: Has the author introduced probability generating functions?  That would be a natural way to use the condition that f(X = x) < 1 everywhere, and the pgf is naturally related to the mgf.

Comment: are the rv independent?

Comment: @user6247850 actually, if the rv are independent, it is exactly the Markov inequality, after a minimization in t

Comment: @Exodd Yeah, I made an arithmetic mistake originally and deleted the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first inequality comes from the fact that they have densities bounded by 1:

$$ \mathbb{E}[e^{-t X_i}] = \int_0^\infty e^{-tx} p_i(x)dx \le \int_0^\infty e^{-tx}dx = \frac 1t. $$

For the second inequality, we can show the bound assuming the $X_i$ are independent.  We have that for any $t > 0$

\begin{align*}
P\left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \le \varepsilon n \right) &= P\left( \sum_{i=1}^n(-t X_i) \ge -\varepsilon nt \right) \\
&= P\left( \exp \left(\sum_{i=1}^n(-t X_i)\right) \ge e^{-\varepsilon nt} \right) \\
&\le e^{\varepsilon nt} \mathbb{E}\left[\exp \left(\sum_{i=1}^n(-t X_i)\right)\right] \\
&= e^{\varepsilon nt}\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[e^{-tX_t}] \\
&\le e^{\varepsilon n t} \frac{1}{t^n} \\
&= \left( \frac{e^{\varepsilon t}}{t} \right)^n.
\end{align*}

Now choose $t$ to minimize $\frac{e^{\varepsilon t}}{t}$.  The value that minimizes $\frac{e^{\varepsilon t}}{t}$ is $t^* := \frac 1{\varepsilon}$, so we have

$$ P\left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \le \varepsilon n \right) \le \left( \frac{e^{\varepsilon t^*}}{t^*} \right)^n = (e \varepsilon)^n.$$

Comment: What does it mean for a density to be bounded by $1$? I’ve never taken probability theory or statistics.

Comment: For a real valued random variable $X$, the density function $p$ is defined by $p(a) := \frac{d}{da} P(X \le a)$.  The fact that the density is bounded by $1$ means that $p(a) \le 1$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh, just the normal definition of boundedness. I assumed it had some special meaning in probability theory. And isn’t every pdf bounded by $1$?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish Of course not - consider a uniform distribution on e.g. $[0,1/n]$ for some positive integer $n$. Then the density is $t\mapsto n\cdot\mathsf 1_{[0,1/2]}(t)$, so a density can take arbitrarily high values. You are probably thinking of the condition that a density must *integrate* to one.

Comment: @user6247850 : The last inequality in your post is incorrect since $t^*$ is the minimizer (actually the inequality goes the other way). But otherwise your argument works.

Comment: @DedekindCuts Good catch!  I'll fix that.